# hasMany and belongsTo in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a *Student* in the `users` table, *Parent* is in the same table, and that *Parent* is the parent of that *Student*.

The *Student* has a *Schedule* in the `schedules` table.

How I can write `hasMany` and `belongsTo` to get the proper relation like in following custom query which works fine:

```php
$schedules = DB::table('users')
  ->join('schedules', 'users.id', '=', 'schedules.studentID')
  ->select('users.*', 'schedules.*', 'users.fname as fname', 'users.lname as lname')
  ->where('users.parent_id',$request->id)
  ->where('schedules.status','1')
  ->where('schedules.status_dead','0')
  ->whereIn('schedules.std_status',[1, 2])
  ->get();
```

As shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Please can you add your `User` and `Schedule` models to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Before the relationship lets create parent scope and find student more elegant way

**User Model**

```
public function scopeByParent($query,$parentId){
    return $query->where("parent_id",$parentId);
}
```

Above scope provide us to get user or users by parent id.

Then create relationships.

**User Model**

```
public function schedules(){
   return $this->hasMany("App\Schedule","studentID","id");
}
```

**Schedule Model**

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsTo("App\User","id","studentID");
}
```

Then lets create our query using above scope and relation.

```
User::with(["schedules" => function ($query) {
    $query->whereStatusAndStatusDead(1, 0)
         ->whereIn('std_status', [1, 2]);
    }])
    ->byParent($request->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Teoman, I only didnt define the scope which seems logical but why I am getting this bracket error in the Eloquent/scope Query

syntax error, unexpected '}
THE 4th line of the query

Comment: @JunaidAbbas I screwed up with semicolons.. But I edited my answer, can you re-copy-paste again ?